# How to read contents of the file in AzureDataLake continuously in the flink streaming?

Tags: azure, apache-flink, flink-streaming, azure-data-lake

I am using flink streaming to read the data from the file in AzureDataLake store.Is there any connector available to read the data from the file stored in Azure Data Lake continuously as the file is updated.How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS) supports REST API interface that is compatible with HDFS and is documented here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datalakestore/webhdfs-filesystem-apis.

Currently there are no APIs or connectors available that poll ADLS and notify/read-data as the files/folders are updated. This is something that you could implement in a custom connector using the APIs provided above. Your connector would need to poll the ADLS account/folder on a recurring basis to identify changes.

Thanks,
Sachin Sheth
Program Manager
Azure Data Lake